# Up grading a ATD 9030 mig welder. What does a choke look like?

Tags: inductor

Up grading a ATD 9030 mig welder. What does a choke look like?
I lost the photos of the wiring before I took it apart.
The one wire on the wire feed motor goes to a choke. [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Annotated welder]

The negative terminal appears to be mis-marked with a red boot.  Ether that is an error, or this model is different from the manual.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I needed to know. I got it the welder back together and it works great.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got the welder back together and it work great.